# Native Base ListItem styles not applying - look broken

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a fresh install of native base + expo and I'm trying to make a list. Usually, no problem but today something just aint right.

[image: Broken lists]

And the code which makes this list.

```
<Container>
    <Content>
      <List>
        <ListItem avatar>
          <Left>
            <Thumbnail source={{ uri: 'http://i.pravatar.cc/100' }} />
          </Left>
          <Body>
          <Text>Awesome group</Text>
          <Text note>Awesome group</Text>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Text>2/13</Text>
          </Right>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem avatar>
          <Left>
            <Thumbnail source={{ uri: 'http://i.pravatar.cc/100' }} />
          </Left>
          <Body>
          <Text>Awesome group</Text>
          <Text note>Awesome group</Text>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Text>1/2</Text>
          </Right>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem avatar>
          <Left>
            <Thumbnail source={{ uri: 'http://i.pravatar.cc/100' }} />
          </Left>
          <Body>
          <Text>Awesome group</Text>
          <Text note>Awesome group</Text>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Text>22/103</Text>
          </Right>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </Content>
  </Container>
```

Really, according to the native base docs, it should actually look like this:

[image: What I expect to see]

It seems like it doesn't apply a lot of the styling driven from the props. E.G the `note` prop on the second line of text doesn't apply and I assume the heights are broken because the `avatar` prop of the list itself does not apply.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok so it turns out this is because I had the extends setup like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
```

But for NativeBase to pick up things properly, you need to import Component and use it like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class App extends Component {
```

And then it all just works :)

Answer (score 1):

i added minimum height styling to the body

```
<Body style={{ minHeight: 70 }}>
    <Text>Awesome group</Text>
    <Text note>Awesome group</Text>
</Body>
```

see what value of min height will work for you